# How do I completely disable Xbox 360 controllers and re-enable them on Windows 10?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

I've found that DS4Windows seems to act up when I have it off or without a controller plugged in. In a nutshell, it's a driver that makes PS4 controllers be read as an Xbox 360 controller. Ever since I installed it, no game that uses Xbox 360 controllers will work all that well because for some reason, every game that has Xbox 360 controller support will read the controller as if it is stuck going up on the analog stick.

I can't find any simple way to disable this, as there is no Xbox 360 controller even enabled in my Control Panel. I check the list and only find the driver for my Gamecube controller in the list. Even uninstalling DS4Windows doesn't help.

I've decided the only solution is to just find a way to disable them altogether and re-enable them. Is there a way to do this? I saw there was a Xbox 360 Controller Utility program, but it does not work with Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try checking device manager? Does it show up there?

Comment: I unfortunately did not find anything there.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not actually sure how you can fix this, sorry.

Comment: Have you read [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/3f1bso/getting_windows_10_and_the_ds4_controller_to_work/)?